# Find most recent email from specific address and reply

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to build a button in excel that allows me to do a "reply to all" to the last email from a specific email address (contact). So far I am stuck on even finding the emails from the person.

The below code is supposed to find the emails from "somebody@gmail.com" (dummy address for example) but after finding all 19 emails in my inbox, filtering for the address then returns 0 results.

I am using excel 2016 and Outlook 2016.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNs As Object
Dim olFldr As Object

Dim olItems As Object
Dim olItemReply As Object
Dim i As Long

Dim emailStr As String
Dim filter As String

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' olFolderInbox
Debug.Print "olFldr: " & olFldr

emailStr = "sombody@gmail.com" '(email address in Excel spreadsheet)
Debug.Print "emailStr: " & emailStr

Set olItems = olFldr.Items
Debug.Print olItems.Count
'finds all 19 items in my inbox with msgbox(olItems.count)


filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = '" & emailStr & "'"
Debug.Print filter

Set olItems = olFldr.Items.Restrict(filter)
Debug.Print olItems.Count

'finds 0 items now ??? why....

End subPrivate Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNs As Object
Dim olFldr As Object

Dim olItems As Object
Dim olItemReply As Object
Dim i As Long

Dim emailStr As String
Dim filter As String

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' olFolderInbox
Debug.Print "olFldr: " & olFldr

emailStr = "sombody@gmail.com" '(email address in Excel spreadsheet)
Debug.Print "emailStr: " & emailStr

Set olItems = olFldr.Items
Debug.Print olItems.Count
'finds all 19 items in my inbox with msgbox(olItems.count)


filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = '" & emailStr & "'"
Debug.Print filter

Set olItems = olFldr.Items.Restrict(filter)
Debug.Print olItems.Count

'finds 0 items now ??? why....

End sub
```

EDIT:
The new code below manages to find the emails in the inbox, sort to most recent, and start a reply. However, I would also like to search in the Archive folder, sub folder "clean up"

[image]

The suggestion from the comment gives me errors with both these attempts:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Part of the issue was that `olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` doesn't work, only when I use `olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6)` do I get a step further, but
`olFldr.Folders` seems not to work as a command on `olFldr`

P.s.: When I loop through my folder names, the name of the Archive folder seems to be "Online Archive - myemail@someemail.com", but also using this name I could not get it to work

Ideally, I would like to look in both the main inbox PLUS the Archive-Cleanup folders together to find the most recent email of Address X

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNs As Object
Dim olFldr As Object

Dim olItems As Object
Dim olItemReply As Object
Dim i As Long

Dim emailStr As String
Dim filter As String
  
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' olFolderInbox

Debug.Print "olFldr: " & olFldr
  
  
emailStr = "Evelyne.Dewulf@apb.be" '(email address in Excel spreadsheet)
Debug.Print "emailStr: " & emailStr


Set olItems = olFldr.Items
Debug.Print olItems.Count
'finds all 19 items in my inbox with msgbox(olItems.count)
MsgBox (olItems.Count)

filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = """ & emailStr & """"
Debug.Print filter

Set olItems = olFldr.Items.Restrict(filter)
Debug.Print olItems.Count

olItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

For i = 1 To olItems.Count
    Debug.Print olItems(i).ReceivedTime
    If olItems(i).Class = 43 Then
        Set olItemReply = olItems(i).Reply
        olItemReply.Display
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Edit 2:
after modifying the code a bit, and selecting the `Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Library` in the vba `Tools` -> `References` I got a step further, but still can't find the right folder.
The olNs.Folders now exists, and gives me folder names when I print it out, but how to get to the archive is still elusive to me:

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim olFldr As Object
Dim olItems As Object
Dim olItemReply As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim i As Long

Dim emailStr As String
Dim filter As String
  
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' olFolderInbox

CurrentRow = ActiveCell.Row

Debug.Print "olFldr: " & olFldr
  
    EmailCol = FindColumn("E-Mail Address", 2) 'find Col

    emailStr = Cells(CurrentRow, EmailCol)

Debug.Print "emailStr: " & emailStr


Set olItems = olFldr.Items
Debug.Print olItems.Count

Dim olArchive As Outlook.Folder
Dim olCleanUp As Outlook.Folder


For Each myobject In olNs.Folders
    MsgBox (myobject)
    Next
    

Set olArchive = olNs.Folders("Archive")
'.... rest as code same as before....
end sub
```

Comment: Please, replace `'filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = '" & emailStr & "'"` with `filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = """ & emailStr & """"`. Email account must be placed between double quotes, not simple...

Comment: that helped. Would you happen to know how to search in a different folder, such as "Archive", and/or a sub folder within "Archive"?  `Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderArchive)` to begin with doesn't work

Comment: In order to be helped you should better specify the need, I would say... Is "Archive" a subfolder of Inbox? If so, does it also have some subfolders (or at least one) and you need to process such a subfolder?

Comment: I will post a new question for it in a bit

Comment: No need of a new question. Please, edit the existing one and specify where the (really) necessary folder exists.

Comment: I have added it, and some problems I ran into in the question update

Comment: I edited my answer and place another solution for "Archive" being a root folder. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working filter variant should be the next one:

```
filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = """ & emailStr & """".
```

Email account name should be placed between double quotes

In order to search in a different folder than `InBox` **and this one is a subfolder of `InBox`, having at least a subfolder named "MyFolder"**, please proceed in the next way:

```
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Archive").Folders("MyFolder")
```

If "Archive" is not a "InBox" subfloder and it is a root folder, please try:

```
Dim olArchive As Outlook.Folder, olCleanUp as Outlook.Folder
Set olArchive = olNs.folders(olNs.CurrentUser.Address).folders("Archive")
set olCleanUp = olArchive.Folders("Cleanup")
```

Thanks to the discussion, we found the error (OPs mistake). The working line needed is

```
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim olCleanUp As Outlook.Folder
'Set olCleanUp = olNs.Folders("myemail@something.com").Folders("Archive").Folders("Cleanup")
```

Comment: Thanks for the new attempt. My Excel VBA does not accept `Outlook.folder`, only `Object` and then on the 2nd line, `.Folders` is not accepted either. I have no idea why this is. My office is the 2016 version

Comment: OK, the `Outlook.folder` issue was fixed by going to `Tools` --> `References` and ticking the Microsoft Outlook 16.0 library. But still, it runs into a wall at the `......Folders("Archive")`

Comment: @Mark It shouldn't matter if you declare it as Object. But, temporarily, try adding a reference to 'Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library' and it will accept that declaration as it is. It is useful due to the fact that it can make suggestions through intellisense. Then, you may declare `Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace` and writing `olNs.` intellisense will make suggestions regarding its properties. You will see `Folders` property... At the end, you can switch to lite binding (declaring as Object)...

Comment: @Mark Looking to the picture you show, the 'Archive' folder looks to be a root folder. I cannot understand what's happening in your installation. In my case it returns the necessary folder and all its properties can be used...

Comment: is there a way I can see which items are available inside olNs? After `olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` the item `olNs = olApp.` gives the dropdown with `GetNamespace("MAPI") available, but then `olNs.` gives no dropdown arguments to choose. I have Dim olApp As Outlook.Application and Dim olNs As Object. Perhaps the problem is in there?

Comment: ok, changed it to `Dim olNs as object` to `Dim olNs as Namespace`, and now I get the argument dropdown, including `Folders`, but it still crashes on `Set olArchive = olNs.Folders(CStr(olNs.CurrentUser))` : run-time error '-2147221233(8004010f)': The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found

Comment: Then, take it piece by piece. Try `Debug.Print olNs.CurrentUser`. What does it return in `Immediate Window`? If there is the problem, try directly writing the used account (instead of `CStr(olNs.CurrentUser)`). Something like "myMail@myDomain.com"...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243314/discussion-between-mark-and-faneduru).

Comment: @Mark Please, try the updated answer. I mean my initial proposition, but changing `olNs.CurrentUser` with `olNs.CurrentUser.Address`... I tested as I initially posted and in my case its default return was `Address`. Now, it is forced to return what is needed...